# Scrapy: Error downloading <GET ['https://[VALID_WEBSITE']>

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm building my own Spider in Scrapy using CrawlSpider and am using a Configuration class to make it configurable. My Configuration has a "Starting_urls" attribute that I'm using to pass to the spider. Looks like it is being correctly passed to the spider but I see the error below (See first line).

```
2018-10-24 11:41:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET ['https://[VALID_WEBSITE']>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\cluster-pD1pIc9C\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\cluster-pD1pIc9C\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 491, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\cluster-pD1pIc9C\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\cluster-pD1pIc9C\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\David\.virtualenvs\cluster-pD1pIc9C\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 64, in download_request
(scheme, self._notconfigured[scheme]))
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme
```

This exact same url works with the command below:

```
scrapy runspider main.py
```

So it must be something in my spider but I'm not sure what:

```
class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
def __init__(self, configuration):
    super(MainSpider, self).__init__(configuration.name)
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    self.configuration = configuration
    self.name = configuration.name
    self.allowed_domains = [configuration.allowed_domains]
    self.start_urls = [configuration.start_urls]
    self.product_link_id = configuration.product_link_id
    self.product_links = set()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is almost always due to an invalid URL. In this case, the URL includes extra single quotes. I had to simply pass in the URL as I enter on a browser.